# split the list and set it on android spinner

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, android-spinner

am getting the arraylist from json parsing.i have to split these arraylist and set it on android spinner.how can i do ??? please help me..

```
 private static final String TAG_SHOPNAME = "retailer_name";
```

The TAG_SHOPNAME containing following values: ["dfdfdfM","dssdfdfdf"] . how can i split these arraylist values ???

```
                        List<String> shoplist = new ArrayList<String>();
                        shoplist.add(product.getString(TAG_SHOPNAME));
                        ArrayAdapter<String> shopadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,shoplist);
```

Now my current output is :

**["dfdfdfM","dssdfdfdf"]**

These value is setting on single spinner list. 
i need to split these arraylist and set it on android spinner like below.

```
dfdfdfM
dssdfdfdf
```

How can i split these and set it on android spinner  ???

What's wrong in my code ??? please give me solution for these ...

**EDIT:**

now i have changed my code like:

```
String retailernames = product.getString(TAG_SHOPNAME);
        retailernames = retailernames.replace("[","");
        retailernames = retailernames.replace("]","");
        retailernames =  retailernames.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
List<String> shoplist = Arrays.asList(retailernames.split(","));
```

Here the product.getString(TAG_SHOPNAME) value is ["dfdfdfM","dssdfdfdf"]

Now my current output is looking like:

```
dfdfdfM"
"dssdfdfdf
```

Here i need the output is like below format:

```
dfdfdfM
dssdfdfdf
```

How can i remove the "" these quotation from the list of strings.

pls give me the solution yaar ...

Comment: Please provide more details. What do you mean by 'split'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to replace " to empty.so we have to use following code:

```
    String retailernames = product.getString(TAG_SHOPNAME);
                    retailernames = retailernames.replace("[","");
                    retailernames = retailernames.replace("]","");
                    retailernames =  retailernames.replace("\"", "");
                    List<String> shoplist = Arrays.asList(retailernames.split(","));
```

Now its working well.hopefully its helpful to anyone.that's why i have posted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
List<String> shoplist = new ArrayList<String>();
                        shoplist.add(product.getString(TAG_SHOP));
                        System.out.println("The Retailer name is"+""+product.getString(TAG_SHOP.toString()));
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
        R.array.planets_array, shoplist );
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: please visit my update code and give me solution.already i done like that ly.but i didn't split these values.

Comment: You need to add all splitted values to your arraylist.